# Is there a way to use .split to split a string into an array

Tags: javascript

So if I were to have a string like "111" how can I turn "111" into [1, 1, 1]. Cause if I were to use `.split(', ')` on the string itself then I would get `['111']`.

Comment: `"111".split("")` ??

Comment: Notice, that the argument of `split` is meant to be the character which to split by, not a separator in the array to be created.

Comment: There's also `[...str]` and you might want to `.map(e => +e)` to get ints.

Comment: @ggorlen thx will give a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let para = "111";  
let arr = para.split('').map(Number);
console.log(arr);   // [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: If you used `Number` you could have shortened it to a nicely looking `.map(Number)`

Comment: Thanks @zerkms for suggestion, updated the same

Answer (score 1):

We can doing a regex split on the lookahead `(?=.)`:

```js
parts = "111".split(/(?=.)/);
console.log(parts);
```

The lookahead `(?=.)` will fire true at every position in between characters, but would fail for the position after the very last character in the string.  Note that lookarounds assert, but do not *consume*.  They get around the problem of using just `(.)`, which would match each letter, but would also consume it in the process.

Comment: Wondering about the reason to use such a (complicated) lookahead instead of simply `.split('')`

Comment: @zerkms No reason...I didn't know about that trick, or else I would have suggested it as well.